# php / ftp upload_max_filesize .htaccess for a specific root?

Tags: php, .htaccess, upload, ftp

is there anything i can do to set the upload_max_filesize in .htaccess ( or another way ) just for one root directory?

> example:
>
> home/admin/uploader.php
>
> home/pdf <- directory where the file should be uploaded

I want to set the filesize to 10M but just for
**home/pdf**  i wont allow any other php script within home/admin a max_filesize of 10M

Whats the best way to do that, or is there even a way to do that? 
 hope someone can help me ;) 
 thx so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at it the wrong way. PHP couldn't care less about where the file is going to end up. It's the script that the file upload is going to that needs to have the memory_limit/upload_max_size settings applied to it.

All you need is

```
<Files uploader.php>
   php_value upload_max_size 10M
</Files>
```